# add an extra search string to the end of an input search using Jquery (for Google Map search)

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a search bar that searches a map. When a user types in a search I want to add "train station, Sydney" to the end of the search string using Jquery, ie:

```
[users search term] + " train station, Sydney"
```

The problem is i'm not sure how to do this since the input does not have a submit bit, (on enter a google map Listener picks up the term)

Any ideas? This is what I tried

JS

```
$("#search-input").keyup(function(e) {
    presser = $('#search-input').val();

if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    $('#search-input').val(presser+' train station, Sydney');
```

HTML

```
<input id="search-input" placeholder="Search" type="text">
```

I think the google map addDomListener picks it up before the value is changed by Jquery

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of this in action? I think I can help, but I need to see your implementation.

Comment: ill upload it right now

Comment: Where is the code that connects the input field to the map/services? It's impossible to answer the question without seeing it.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot exactly, thats what I thought, all the code I have is in the index page. I got the input code from google, I cant tell how it connects with the map, its like its magic

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `blur` event, so when the `input` loses focus, it'll add that text:

```
$("#search-input").blur(function() {
    this.value += " train station, Sydney";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be elegant, but I would do this with plain JS to get going. After that, this is what I would use for code:`var e = getElementById('search-input');
var i = e.value; var j = i + " " + "train station, Sydney` and then make the value of the search `var j`.

The reason that I would use Plain JS is the fact that I find it easier to work with than jQuery, although I have worked with it as well. Also, the Google maps API is in JS, so I would  be stay on one track... :)